# OP AMP level shifter circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc

Lets say I would like to measure a 12 V battery with an ADC that has a lot lower reference voltage, like 3 V. For this battery, I don't need the full range, but only 10 - 12 V (so the ADC value 0 could be 10 V). If I use a simple voltage divider, I will measure the whole voltage range, also bellow 10 V. Is there an Op Amp configuration circuit that could be used to obtain this functionality?

Comment: A differential amplifier is what you’re after. Also known as a subtractor.

Comment: Is everything powered by your battery, including the ADC and op amp? How much current can you spare for your circuit, both when it is in use, and quienscently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhfMnP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 and R2 divide down the input voltage by a factor of about 1/4 (0.2492) to make voltage X.  X = 2.492V when +12V_BAT is 10V.  X = 2.991V when +12V_BAT is 12V.

The difference between X and 3V_REF is amplified by a factor of about 5.9.

The overall equation for the output is...

VOUT = 3V - (3V - V_BAT * 0.2492) * 5.9.

You can of course scale up the resistors by some factor to reduce current if needed.  Also, I would recommend using 0.1% resistors.

**DETAILED MATH:**

The equation for the circuit is...
VOUT = REF - (REF - G1 * VIN) * G2
Where...
G1 =  R2 / (R2 + R1)
G2 = R4 / R10
REF is the 3V reference voltage.

To solve for G1 we first choose a maximum input voltage (lets call it VIN1) for which the output = REF.  This leads to the following equation...
REF = REF - (REF - G1 * VIN1) * G2
Rearranging and solving for G1 gives....
G1= REF / VIN1 
In your case VIN1 = 12V and REF = 3V, so G1 = 3V / 12V = 1/4.  Picking R1 = 100K and R2 = 33.2K gives this ratio (0.2492).

Knowing G1 we can now solve for G2.  To do this, we pick some minimum input voltage (lets call it Vin2) for which we want the output to be 0V.  This leads to the following equation...

0V = REF - (REF - G1 * VIN2) * G2
Rearranging and solving for G2 gives....
G2 = REF /(REF - G1 * VIN2)
In your case REF = 3V, VIN2 = 10V, and G1 = 0.2492.
Therefore G2 = 3V / (3V - 10V * 0.2492) = 5.911.

Picking R10 = 10K and R4 = 59K gives the required G2 (5.90).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  With a unity-gain differential amplifier configuration, you can subtract a DC voltage such a 10 Vdc from the varying input signal.  This would translate the 10 V - to - 12 V input signal range to a 0 V - to - 2 V output signal range.

However, you must pay attention to the operating characteristics of the opamp, particularly its input and output voltage operating ranges.  For example, even a "rail-to-rail" output stage will not go down to 0.00 V when required.

What power sources are available for the circuit?  If a negative voltage source is available, then you can get a true 0.00 V output if required.  If you can stand a little bit of non-linearity at the low end of the output range, then many opamps can work with a single supply voltage.

To prevent possible problems with the high end of the input signal range being too close to the power rail, I would attenuate the input by 50% and use a precision voltage reference to produce the offset voltage of 5.0 V.